# c++ Segmentation fault when taking int input from user in terminal but not xcode

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cin

<strike>I was having issues reading in a file with xcode so I decided to switch to terminal to test it, however in terminal I am getting a segmentation fault when the following function executes for (only when choosing 1). Any Ideas?</strike>

Turns out it is a problem with my reading a file in. I am going to post another question handling that.

```
struct system {
character player;
};
struct character {
string name;
ushort money;
ushort intelligence;
ushort time;
ushort steps;
ushort score;
};

bool get_number ( int& number )
{
while ( !( cin >> number ) ) {
    if ( cin.eof() )
        return false;
    else {
        char ch;
        cin.clear();
        cout<<"Invalid input, please try again: ";
        while (cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n' );
    }
}
return true;
}

void viewMenu(menu menuChoice) {
cout << menuChoice.options;
cout << "\nPlease choose an option: ";
int number;
get_number(number);
if (menuChoice.choice == 0) {
    if (number == 1) {
        struct system game;
        startGame(playerName);
    }
    else if (number == 2) {
        viewScores(gameScoreboard);
        viewMenu(startMenu);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Goodbye";
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Again, this all works fine in xcode, but in terminal it fails when choosing "1".

Comment: what is the definition of 'struct system game'?   Try to run it with a debuger (gdb if you are on linux) and see where it crashes.

Comment: @Soren edited to show 2 of the structs. I'm on osx, do you know of any debuggers built into osx?

Comment: `playerName` is not declared. You might have a problem in `startGame`.